# Android manifest POST_NOTIFICATIONS missing import

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-permissions

Trying to implement the notification permission for android 13 or "Tiramisu" but failed to get the import for that permission.

Currently:
targeted SDK version is 32
compile SDK version is 32

I've declared it also in manifiest as below:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
```

import i'm using:

```
import android.Manifest
```

- But even not getting import in my fragment.

[image]

Comment: weird, [it is there](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#POST_NOTIFICATIONS). try to restart your Android Studio with cache cleaning (File ->Invalidate caches -> Invalidate and Restart button)

Comment: Does there any role for the Gradle version here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
     android {
     namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdkVersion 33//update this

     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdkVersion 33//update this
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: **Note:** As of 26-05-2022 android 13 is not yet stable

Comment: Just thought it saved my day in advance. Thanks for this.

Comment: This did not work for me...

Answer (score 46):

Just add this import:

```
import android.Manifest
```

Comment: I wonder why Android Studio doesn't provide a quick action to add the import for us.

Comment: Android Studio also sees a Manifest class for your apps package, so doesn't see it as a missing import.

Answer (score 29):

I solved it by using *compileSdkVersion 33* in the gradle file at the Module level. Then it allowed me to use the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission without any issue.
[image: Gradle Settings]

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Did you install the Android API 33 SDK?

Comment: Oh yes, that is definately installed.

Comment: Well, I can't definately help if you don't provide additional info.

Comment: Btw, it does work now, it was a typo.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. And, yeah, tone is hard to decipher online.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Funny it wasn't enough to have compileSdkVersion in  android block, it had to be under defaultConfig as well... Would never thought about it.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem,

**Steps to fix :**

**Install SDK Platforms**
`SDK Platform 33`
`Android TiramisuPrivacy Sandbox Preview`

[image]

**Install SDK Tools :**
Android SDK build Tools 33
[image]

Comment: Android TiramisuPrivacy Sandbox Preview is not needed.  Try to File -> Invalidate Caches...

Answer (score 4):

You need to prefix the Manifest statement with android., e.g.,

```
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Answer (score 2):

Set **targetSDKVersion** to ***33***.

If for some reason it complains about your minimum supported and you're in no position to update, use the following instead:

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

Answer (score 1):

Import below line

```
import android.Manifest
```

then use,

> android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS

instead of

> Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS

Answer (score 0):

just import
`import android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS as POST_NOTIFICATIONS`
and use as
`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, POST_NOTIFICATIONS)`
it's work perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are coming here for a react-native that uses 'react-native-gesture-handler' this is because react-native-gesture-handler has a new 2.10.0 version, if you downgrade it to 2.9.0 it should work